# xul runner: does it require Firefox on the target OS?

Tags: xulrunner

Xul Runner: does it require installed version of Firefox on the OS? 
or does it compile its own web engine?

The dependancies are unclear to me, even when looking at their documentation.

Perhaps let me be clearer: The XULrunner can compile using firefox or you can compile without.

My question is this: If I were to create a XUL user interface, and use XULrunner, will the application created contain everything to display the user interface, or is it like .hta which requires IE. Hence my question: does firefox have to be installed on the target operating system?

Comment: As I know it's separate package on linux and you can install it without FF, but it will contain major part of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. XULRunner is an independent application, it has everything necessary to run XUL-based apps. This "everything necessary" is to a large part identical to what you find in Firefox but not entirely identical (some browser-specific things are missing). This also means that there is (at least) one catch: if you install XULRunner as part of your application you will also be responsible for updating it regularly - it has all the same security vulnerabilities as Firefox.

Comment: Thanks Wladimir. Asked and answered. I also found this helpful     http://www.kodewerx.org/wiki/A_Brief_Introduction_To_XULRunner:_Part_1

Answer (score 0):

Since there is a (static/shared) library for libxul, i think the answer for your question was not needed to install firefox.

(dunno if it's helping you or not)

```
cat /usr/lib/pkgconfig/libxul-embedding.pc 
prefix=/usr
sdkdir=/usr/lib/xulrunner-devel-6.0.1
includedir=/usr/include/xulrunner-6.0.1
idldir=/usr/share/idl/xulrunner-6.0.1

Name: libxul-embedding
Description: Static library for version-independent embedding of the Mozilla runtime
Version: 6.0.1
Requires: nspr >= 4.8.9
Libs: -L${sdkdir}/lib -lxpcomglue -ldl
Cflags: -DXPCOM_GLUE -I${includedir}
```

Comment: My questio nis not about firefox per se, thanks. I have firefox installed, my question was if I move over to using XULrunner as the bootstrap to the gui, and XUL to formulate the gui, is that sufficient, or do you have to actually upload Firefox onto the operating system where XULrunner functions.